# ui-sref doesn't generate a href, despite of router conf and state in a $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having some problems in understanding where to find my mistake. I have a state stored in a $scope variable.
Inspecting the page, I see that the right state is stored in the ui-sref property in the html..with a strange generated comment == $0 and another very curious behaviour is that if I hardcode the state name (so without keeping it from the scope variable), it works and I can obtain the href!

[image]

I have a ui-view in the html template, and the relative states:

```
.state('push', {
            url: "/push/:type",
            templateUrl: "firstday__push.do",
            controller: 'PushController'
})
```

and this is my controller:

```
(function (module) {
"use strict";
var HeaderController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $state) {
    console.log("Header Controller");
    $scope.previous = "";

    $scope.showBack = function () {
       if ($state.current.name !== 'home') {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    };

    $scope.goTo = function (dest) {
        if(dest) {
            $state.go(dest);    
        } else {
            $state.go('home');
        }

    };

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
        $scope.previous = from.name;
        console.log($scope.previous);
        console.log(from);
    });

    var nanobar = new Nanobar({
        classname : 'progress'
    });
};

module.controller("HeaderController", HeaderController);

}(angular.module("firstday_app")));
```

and in the template:

From the screenshot I can always see the correct values, so really don't know what's wrong in my code. Any idea?

Thanks in advance for your precious support!

Comment: The `== $0` is meant to be there. You can use the `$0` variable in the console to reference the selected dom element.

Comment: Can you post your template code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to you trying to assign only the state name to the `$scope.previous` property.  If that state name is something such as your `push` state, it will not be a valid state as `push` requires a `type` parameter for ui-sref to resole to a valid state:

```
ui-sref="push({type:'someType'})"
```

The better approach (assuming you always want to go to the previous state) may be to use a function to send the user back on click:

```
$scope.goPrevious = function(){
    // Make sure $window is injected in your controller.
    $window.history.back();
}
```

And your click diretive:

```
ng-click="goPrevious()"
```

Comment: Hi @chrisboustead! Thanks a lot! Yesterday I achieved that with:      $scope.back = function () {
    $state.go($scope.previous);
        }; but you're more expert than me so I updated with your approach! I didn't understand the push discussion, I will study that.. thanks a lot!